# Action script is slow capturing microphone audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, signal-processing

I'm facing some performance problem implementing an audio capture with ActionScript.

I've created a flash.media.Microphone instance with a sample rate of 22100Hz and I want to fill a buffer of 2048 samples.

Here how I'm doing that:

```
var samples = new Array<Float>();
static var start:Float = Date.now().getTime();

public static function initMic(index = -1) {                
    mic = flash.media.Microphone.getMicrophone(index);
    if (mic == null) {
        getMicFailed();
        return;
    }

    mic.setLoopBack(false);
    mic.rate = Std.int(22);
    mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
    mic.setUseEchoSuppression(false);
    mic.addEventListener(flash.events.SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);       
}

public static function micSampleDataHandler(e) {
    var buffersize = 2048;
    var data = e.data;      

    if (samples.length < buffersize) {          
        while(data.bytesAvailable && samples.length < buffersize) { 
            var sample:Float = data.readFloat(); 
            samples.push(sample);
        } 

        if (samples.length < buffersize) {  
            return;
        }
    }

    flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("javascriptCallback", samples);           
    samples = new Array<Float>();

    trace(Date.now().getTime() - start);
    start = Date.now().getTime();
}
```

It takes 120/140 milliseconds to fill the buffer!
In your experience, that is a good performance value? There is something I can do to make it faster?

EDIT: The "Javascript Callback" is calling an empty javascript function right now.

Comment: At 22100Hz sampling rate, it takes a minimum of 93ms to fill a buffer of 2048 samples. I suspect a large part of the balance (some 30-50ms) is spent in `processSamples` rather than just collecting data in the buffer.

Comment: Hi SleuthEye, thank you for your answer! I changed my code, the  `processSamples` is just calling an empty javascript function. There is some performance issue in the `ExternalInterface.call` method? How did you calculate those 93ms? There is a mathematical formula? Thank you again!

Comment: 93ms (or 92.6696...) comes from 2048 samples multiplied by the period of a sample (1 over the sampling frequency) which in this case is 1/22100. Best for performance issues is to use a profiler (though I do not have a specific one to recommend for javascript). How did you measure your timings?

Comment: I edited the code to show how I'm measuring timings. If i completly remove the call to `ExternalInterface` i got 99/110 milliseconds...